# Finding mysql username and password

Tags: macos, mysql

I have used the binary installer on my mac and use the following to start mysql.

`sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`

It seems to start ok, but i haven't set up any passwords for users yet. I followed the instructions here from MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html

`mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;`

This just returns `-bash: mysql: command not found`

I'm a first time mac user and don't really know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it i think

`export set MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64`

`export set PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL_HOME/bin`